# AWS Athena Delta Lake version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, delta-lake

Which version of **Delta Lake** does **AWS Athena** support as a reader?

I have a lot of Databricks jobs that create tables with deletion vectors enabled by default, so I was wondering if Athena already supports Delta Version 2.3. And does it support table features already?

Comment: Note the difference between Delta's version vs [table protocol version](https://docs.delta.io/latest/versioning.html#features-by-protocol-version). To handle Deletion vectors Athena should support reading tables with `minReaderVersion >= 3`, I couldn't find if that's the case in the doc.

Comment: Yes, but with 2.3 SCAN is supported for Deletion Vector Tables, which would equal a Reader Version of >= 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just spoke to AWS support. The version of Delta Lake that Athena supports is not public, but it does not support Deletion Vectors today.